# can not run git gc .. any solution?

Tags: git

Hello dearest community,

I am just a regular use of git in Windows. Now that the git gui display confirmation about whether to compress database to remove loose object or not. But there are error saying that it can some file. After googling, I found that it's about `git gc` command, here is the result :

```
$ git gc
Counting objects: 928, done.
error: unable to find f2c10eb0524b872b4204b850cae5653ddadeb700
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (902/902), done.
fatal: unable to read f2c10eb0524b872b4204b850cae5653ddadeb700
error: failed to run repack
```

Because of this, git-gui always display loose object dialog. 
How can I fix my repository, and is this bad?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run git show f2c10eb0524b872b4204b850cae5653ddadeb700 and see if you get output. If not means that packed object is corrupt. You might want to look at this -
http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/How-to-replace-a-single-corrupt-packed-object-td680795.html